Estimating Token Consumption and Response Token Count in Databricks using dbrx-instruct
I'm trying to understand how to estimate the token consumption and response token count in Databricks using dbrx-instruct. I want to create a function that can predict the number of tokens I'll be requesting based on my query and how many tokens I'll receive in response. This information is crucial for estimating the costs incurred.
Here are my specific questions:

How does dbrx-instruct estimate the tokens sent and received?
Are there any guidelines or best practices for estimating token usage?
Is there a simpler method or tool available to achieve this estimation?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

As stated in the official Databricks blog post:

DBRX is a transformer-based decoder-only large language model (LLM) that was trained using next-token prediction. /.../ It uses the GPT-4 tokenizer as provided in the tiktoken
repository. /.../

And later on, the GPT-4 tokenizer is mentioned again:

In addition to better data quality, another
important contributor to this token-efficiency may be the GPT-4
tokenizer, which has a large vocabulary and is believed to be
especially token-efficient.

The DBRX models, which dbrx-instruct is part of, use the GPT-4 tokenizer. If you take a look at the OpenAI cookbook example on How to count tokens with tiktoken, you can see that GPT-4 models use the cl100k_base encoding.
So, as far as I understand, the tokenization is identical to the GPT-4 models, which means you have two options:

Option 1: Use tiktoken
This is the programmatic way to tokenize text.
If you run get_tokens.py, you'll get the following output:

9

get_tokens.py
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_name)
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

print(num_tokens_from_string("Hello world, let's test tiktoken.", "cl100k_base"))


Option 2: Use OpenAI's Tokenizer UI
It's the fastest and easiest way to tokenize text.


As you can see, either we use tiktoken or OpenAI's Tokenizer UI, we get 9 tokens for Hello world, let's test tiktoken. text.
